# uri_to_assoc issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

This is my code

`$default = array('location', 'id', 'page');
$url_info = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3, $default); 
var_dump($url_info);`

If my url is

`http://localhost/cidbg/test/uritest/location/india/page/8/id/58`

Then my $url_info is ok.

`array
  'location' => string 'india' (length=5)
  'page' => string '8' (length=1)
  'id' => string '58' (length=2)`

But when my url is

`http://localhost/cidbg/test/uritest/location/india/page//id/58`

Then my $url_info is like this.

`array
  'location' => string 'india' (length=5)
  'page' => string 'id' (length=2)
  58 => boolean false
  'id' => boolean false`

The page variable is missing there. Actually am expecting page to FALSE. Is there anyway to achive this? I mean if a value is missing, then that name should be false.

Answer (score 0):

Apache will automatically convert double slash to a single slash. So

`http://localhost/cidbg/test/uritest/location/india/page//id/58` is same as `http://localhost/cidbg/test/uritest/location/india/page/id/58`

So you can either  search for a complicated way to retaining the double slash using .htaccess (I'm not sure if that's possible) or you can pass an extra param (like 0) instead of empty.

`http://localhost/cidbg/test/uritest/location/india/page/0/id/58`

Comment: thank you Vikk, but i cant give 0, that value may be null. Thats the issue.